# Can you include an Azure DevOps wiki inside an existing repository?

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps has a built in wiki feature that allows either a Provisioned Wiki (a single wiki for the project), or multiple wiki repositories.

My question is with regards to the repository wikis, and if you can add the wiki to an existing repository so that both the code and wiki documentation are co-located?

So rather than having these repos;

- backend
- backend-wiki
- frontend
- frontend-wiki

There are 2 code repositories and within each is the wiki markdown code?

The idea behind this is so that if a code change is made within the repository, then documentation changes can be made within the same branch so will reflect in the Pull Requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the short answer is yes
You can use any *.md files in a code repo as wiki, you simply go to the Project, Wiki, select "Publish Code as Wiki", point it to the Git Repo and select the Folder you want as root for your wiki. You can do that with as many Git Repos as you need.

In your case, if I understood you right you would add the wiki md files to the main branch of the backend/frontend repo, then go to the Project, Wiki, select "Publish Code as Wiki" and select the existing gitrepo and select the main branch and the folder with the wiki files in the options.

Comment: Excellent! It's easy when you know how! Thanks for the answer. I've now for my project wiki up and running.